# ES6: unexpected behavior when using arrow function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

In the first case, I use an arrow function for `getColor`, and the second case I use an anonymous function. 
I expected that I have the same result for both cases, but not:

**Case 1:**

```
const Car = {
    color: 'blue',
    getColor: function () { console.log(this.color); }
};

Car.getColor(); // I get 'blue'
```

**Case 2:**

```
const Car = {
    color: 'blue',
    getColor: () => console.log(this.color)
};

Car.getColor(); // I get undefined
```

Is there any concept I don't understand on arrow functions?

Comment: In second case context of this is `window` not Car object

Comment: The question was already asked, sorry for the duplication